# recv in Visual C++ is not returning any data until newline received

Tags: c, winsock, recv

I'm having a very strange issue in Visual C++ where I'm using Winsock recv. I'm just trying to receive data 1 byte at a time, but recv never returns any data at all until a newline is in the stream. I'm not doing anything special. I'm just accepting a socket connection from a client and then calling recv once it's open.

I've tried connecting to it with putty, teraterm, and telnet on a linux box. In all cases, recv doesn't return any data until after I've hit enter in the client! First I was using SDL_Net (as my program uses SDL anyway and I want to be cross-platform), and I had this problem. I figured it was an SDL_Net problem, so I converted it to just use Winsock and still have the same issue!

Comment: When you're in doubt which side is misbehaving use a network sniffer like Wireshark to see the trues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *client* is probably not sending anything until you hit enter, due to line buffering -- `stdio` usually buffers the input until it sees a newline (this allows you to, among other things, edit the line you're writing before sending it).

If you have any control over the client, you may be able to put the console in a "raw" mode, which sends keys as soon as they are sent. How you do this is platform dependent.

Comment: That was my first thought and it's why I tried different clients. putty in raw mode, tera term, as well as telnet on Debian.

Comment: It seems *highly* likely that line buffering is to blame. There's simply no reason for `recv` to treat any bytes specially. Have you tried sending bytes using a socket API directly? Maybe try `netcat`?

Comment: You're right, if I connect with a VB6 socket and send a byte at a time it comes right through.